# why is the select2 dropdown menu only showing in the first row of my table?

Tags: html, jquery-select2

Hello everyone I am trying to make a dropdown menu with select2. I ran into a problem with my select2 dropdown menu's. The select2 dropdown menu is only showing in the first row of my table for some reason. But I do not understand why this is happening. I want the select2 dropdown menu's to show in the whole admin column and not just the first row.

**here is my table code**

```
                    <tbody id="myTable">
                        <tr class="table">
                            <td class="table">email</td>
                            <td class="table">name</td>
                            <td class="table">
                                <form>
                                    <select id="isAdmin">
                                        <option selected>false</option>
                                        <option value="false">false</option>
                                        <option value="true">true</option>
                                    </select>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                            <td class="table">bhv</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

**Here is my select2 code**

```
    var isAdmin;
    $('#isAdmin').select2({
        placeholder: 'Choose..',
    });
    $("#isAdmin").on("select2:select select2:unselect", function (e) {
        //this returns all the selected item
        isAdmin = $(this).val();
    })
```

**Here is the table in the browser**
[image: Here is the table in the browser]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use class instead of Id,

You cannt have 2 or more items on a page with the same ID value.

```
                <tbody id="myTable">
                    <tr class="table">
                        <td class="table">email</td>
                        <td class="table">name</td>
                        <td class="table">
                            <form>
                                <select class="isAdmin">
                                    <option selected>false</option>
                                    <option value="false">false</option>
                                    <option value="true">true</option>
                                </select>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                        <td class="table">bhv</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

Then
var isAdmin;
$('.isAdmin').select2({
placeholder: 'Choose..',
});
$(".isAdmin").on("select2:select select2:unselect", function (e) {
//this returns all the selected item
isAdmin = $(this).val();
})